# Unicoins: divide everyones rep by10!

Tags: discussion, unicoins

[image]

Did I understand that right?  Everybody else's rep?

- Now is that everybody in a specific forum? Everybody who answered a particular Question?
- Can I be selective and spare my friends and sock puppets?
- Also, what if I want it more than once. Can it be used repeatedly? I want it 20 times. Who needs increased rep when you can just squash everyone else's!
- Is there a cure? What if some ***$%^#*** uses it one me, is there a "**reverse rep hit**" I can buy with Unicoins?

PS, I like the remove downvote arrow from all my Q's and A's, but no one seems to have thought up **Remove all downvotes to date!**

Comment: 20 times? So, reduced by a factor of 10^20? That's just harsh.

Comment: Not harsh... Petty. The difference is subtle but important.

Comment: "[An eye for an eye will leave everyone blind.](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2010/12/27/eye-for-eye-blind/)" meets [Zeno's Paradox](http://platonicrealms.com/encyclopedia/Zenos-Paradox-of-the-Tortoise-and-Achilles).

Comment: No, no, no. The goal is to blind all others and keep my own vision. How many unicoins for that? will I need serious backing?

Comment: I think unicorns only affect what you see yourself, not what others see

Comment: @LouisSomers - Not so, unicoins are real. I'm saving up right now for the almighty "Shut down teh interwebs for everyone else", see how you post skeptic comments then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes for everyone but you, no options to exclude anyone from your bringing wrath. Also, If someone else does it your rep will be cut by ten also, bummer.

Comment: so not fair it can be done to me. On the upside, i just multiplied mine by 10 so im ready!

Answer (score -4):

Unicoins are just something to play around with and do not actually have any real impact on anybodies accounts.  If you want to verify this yourself then try to buy some, but do not worry if you do not have a credit card because they accept gold and diamonds as well...